# How can I see which line a program is using?

Tags: visual-studio

I want to see which line my program is using. For example, the program is on line 231, but I don't know that. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: This is a very poorly worded question - open to much interpretation.  While we value brevity here, you need to include enough detail as to be unambiguous as well.  You'll find the right balance.  You can start by trying to improve this question.

Comment: @SamAxe Thank you. I will try and improve my future questions. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While running in debug mode from Visual Studio you can:

1. Set a breakpoint.  The debugger will kick in and pause execution on
   that line.
2. Press the "Pause" button on the VS toolbar.  Program
   execution will immediately pause and the debugger will show you what
   line its on.
3. Write code involving `System.Diagnostics.Debugger` (such as `Debugger.Break();`) where you beed the debugger to pause execution.  This method has the added bonus of not relying on Visual Studio to be the debugger - if you're one of *those* weird-os. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Tools->Options->Text Editor->C# and the check line numbers.

Then set a breakpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Only thing that comes to mind is for you to put a comment at the end of each line with the line number, then look at the comment as you step through.  But that would only work in debug mode and only after hitting a breakpoint.

One major problem trying this in regular mode, running as normal, is that C# does not run.  It compiles into byte code, and there is not a one-to-one correlation between C# lines and IL lines.  So I'm afraid in that sense, this cannot be done.

Comment: Not to mention if you add or remove a line in your code, all your comments have to be manually updated.